# Flutter StreamBuilder continue to be updated after push another screen

Tags: flutter, bloc, stream-builder

I'm totally lost with Flutter Bloc and streams..
After a lot of debugging I figure out the BlocBuilder doesn't really work well with streams, emit happening but the widget doesn't updating probably it's not enough sensitive to small changes (in a list object fields..). So I have tried StreamBuilder that will listen to the stream of a list, that works fine even though it doesn't really feel comfortable - what really the bloc for if it doesn't update the widget on changes well?

Now the problem is after I push another page the StreamBuilder continued to be updated with data.. Is there anyway to pause it - seems like a big waist

Comment: it is by design that they would receive the stream data even not visible. You might want to redesign the data flow as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want BlocBuilder to change based on a list update then you need to make a copy of the list and emit that.

```
// in bloc function...

final updatedList = [...state.myList]; // making a copy of the list using spread operator

// update your list
// emit updatedList and BlocBuilder will react
```

There's no reason to have to use StreamBuilders. Using a Bloc widget, once that page is off of the navigation stack, it won't react to any changes. If you push a new page to the stack without popping off the previous one, then any listeners will still be active.

You can use the `buildWhen` or `listenWhen` filters of the BlocBuilder and BlocListener widgets to check where you are in the navigation if you need the previous page to remain in the navigation stack.

```
BlocListener<YourBloc, YourState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) {
        // check if current page is the current page before reacting to state changes
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
         ...
        },
    );
```

Comment: Maybe I need to override the operator == of the state - doe's Equtable object compare each list item?

Comment: OK the operation == was fine.. the problem was the object in the list needed to be rebuild as well, it was not enough to update a field sense it's a pointer..